# On iPhone 8 Plus I need To access and upload to Facebook or YouTube, video clips I made Several years ago

Tags: iphone, photos, video, facebook

Trying to upload some of my old video clips from my camera roll a few years ago, but in YouTube I  cant Scroll back far enough.

I  read Where I  can Touch the video and get a sub menu to share to various platforms but try as I  might , YouTube is not one of them.

The other option is to ‘copy’ or duplicate my clip- in the hope such copy will reappear  in with current camera roll photos and videos.

But the date stamp of the old clip places it right next to the old clip - so I’m actually no better off. Can’t find a way of ‘moving’ it to current date or position in camera roll.

Tried to ‘share it to an album’ with only a few videos in it but YouTube doesn’t have any option to ‘change directory’ and ‘find’ the clip. Facebook doesn’t seem to allow me to search for that photo album and select the clip I  want.

Anothe example is: I  see A post on my Facebook RV site where someone is asking a question and I  already Have made a ‘tips’ video about the solution but I  can’t Get that clip into the current post in response.

All I  can Do is upload ( or share) It to ‘Only Me’ and then I  can’t Link or show it in my response to that post.

Soo frustrating. It’s all ok if it’s a recent clip because it can be located in camera roll readily accessible but with about 10,000 photos to scroll through there’s no easy way to get there given both programs search limitations.

Help

Bewildered Barry